# Arrays of undefined size in the constructor C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

I am trying to find a way to define an array of unknown size in a class and "fill it in" using a constructor. Here is a simple example to give you a rough idea of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyClass{
public:
    string Name;
    double x[];
    double y[];

    MyClass(string aName, double aX, double aY){
        Name=aName;
        x[]=aX;
        y[]=aY;
    }

};

int main() {
  MyClass object1("Object1",{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0});
}
```

Obviously, there are plenty errors, so I do not know where to start and how to achieve my goal!

Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT

Here is a working solution based on the answers to this question. Thanks everyone!

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyClass{
public:
    string Name;
    vector<double> x;
    vector<double> y;

    MyClass(string aName, vector<double> aX, vector<double> aY){
        Name=aName;
        x=aX;
        y=aY;
    }

};

int main() {
  MyClass object1("Object1",{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0});
  cout<<object1.Name<<endl;
  cout<<object1.x[1]<<endl;
  cout<<object1.y[2]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: C++ does not work this way. All arrays must have a fixed size. Otherwise, use `std::vector`.

Comment: As explained in the answers and comments, you cannot do that in C++. Take a look at the containers available for using the one that better fits your needs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variable length arrays are not supported in standard C++.

In your case `std::vector<double> x;` &c. are virtually drop-in replacements, and certainly are if you were to write

```
MyClass object1{"Object1",{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0}};
```

instead, noting that this will not call your constructor, which you are free to remove rather than attempting to fix the compilation errors.

Answer (score 5):

An array of indeterminate size is an incomplete type. There can not be variables of incomplete type. Thus, your member variables are ill formed. Array variables, members included, must have a compile time constant size.

If you need arrays of runtime size, you need to allocate it dynamically. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector`.